# Area Integral of $(x+y)^{2n}$ over unit disc

Tags: calculus, integration, area

See image for specific details of the question:
[image: Question]

For part (i) is it enough to state that $f(x,y)= (\sin x + \cos x)^{2n+1}$ has the property $f(-x,-y)=-f(x,y)$ and so it will cancel out over a symmetric area of integration.

Also, could someone give me a hint on how to work out the integral of $(x+y)^{2n}$ over the unit disc- should I proceed by using integration by parts? It seems that, after I have changed to plane polar coordinates, I should factor out the $\cos(\theta)$ in order to use the identity that they have provided but I am unable to see how to isolate $\cos^{2n}(\theta)$.

Any hints would be much appreciated, thanks.

Comment: Welcome to MSE.  Please type your questions instead of posting images.  Images can't be browsed and are not accessible to those using screen readers.  If you need help formatting math on this site, here's a [tutorial](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference)

Comment: @saulspatz Ok I'll try to update it now, thanks for letting me know.

Comment: Hint: $\sqrt{2} r \cos(\theta - \frac{\pi}{4}) = r \cos \theta + r \sin \theta$.

Comment: To satrt with, note that you have to surround MathJax commands with `$` signs.  `$(x^2+y^2)^2$` shows up as $(x^2+y^2)^2$.

Comment: Using the fact that you have an odd function is harder for multiple integrals. Try the following: split $D$ up into quadrants. Wherever $x<0,$ change variables (you are allowed to use single variable change of variables) so that $x>0.$ Your limits will change. And wherever you have $y<0,$ change it to $y>0.$ Things will cancel out more or less by the property you stated.

Comment: Thanks a lot everyone!

Comment: Maybe yo want to use polar coordinates. secavara's trick may simplify things further.